# use geolocation to represent the datas

Tags: geolocation

[geolocation picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayzGj.png)

I want to show data bubble chart on google map. 
like the picture above. 
how should I approach this problem with geo-location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [google api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) and adding makers based on lat & long to show the "bubbles" by setting the image icon. Depending on your requirements you could create an array of markers and show/hide them on the map.

```
// retrieve div for map
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");

// setup map options - look at google api docs for more info
var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(50, -50),
zoom: 4
};

// initialize map
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

// create marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: { lat: locations[i].Latitude, lng: locations[i].Longitude },
icon: { url: yourBubbleImage() }
});

//to show
marker.setMap(map);

//to hide
marker.setMap(null);
```

You also might need to register with google to use the gmaps api

Answer (score 0):

"Marker clustering" is the search term you are looking for.

Google provides a JavaScript library on [GitHub named MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclusterer).

Basically you need to include the JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
```

and use the MarkerClusterer object:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }
```

If you need more information have a look at the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) or the [examples](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html).